# URLSession Credentials Caching Allowing Authentication with Incorrect Credentials

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, nsurlcredential, nsurlcredentialstorage

I am trying to communicate with my company's API in my iOS app.  I am using the standard URLSession.

The API will load balance and redirect to a different server automatically, so I've implemented the URLSessionDelegate and URLSessionTaskDelegate methods which handle the redirects.

When I initially login I will get redirected from http://our.api.com to http://our1.api.com or some other version of the API with a different server number.  The first time I authenticate with http://our1.api.com it will honor the passed in Authorization header and challenged URLCredential.  But if I try to authenticate against the same API again with known bad credentials, the old URLCredential is used and I am able to get into the API when I should not be able to.

Is there a way to force URLSession to *never* use the cached URLCredential, or otherwise clear out the cached URLCredentials?

Creating the URLSession

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Accept":"application/xml",
                                    "Accept-Language":"en",
                                    "Content-Type":"application/xml"]
    config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    config.urlCache = nil
    self.urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
```

Calling to the API

```
var request = URLRequest(url: thePreRedirectedUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("Basic username:password", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

let task = urlSession?.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in                        
        // pass endpoint results to completion block
        completionBlock(data, response, error)
    })

    // run the task
    if let task = task {
        task.resume()
    }
```

URLSessionDelegate and URLSessionTaskDelegate

```
extension ApiManager: URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    if challenge.previousFailureCount == 0 {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(user: username, password: password, persistence: .none))

    } else {
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                task: URLSessionTask,
                willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse,
                newRequest request: URLRequest,
                completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {

        var newRequest = URLRequest(url: request.url!)
        newRequest.addValue("Basic username:password", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        newRequest.httpMethod = task.originalRequest?.httpMethod
        newRequest.httpBody = task.originalRequest?.httpBody
        completionHandler(newRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is to delete the credential from the user's (macOS) or app's (iOS) keychain.

See [Updating and Deleting Keychain Items](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/updating_and_deleting_keychain_items) on Apple's developer website for details, but basically:

```
NSDictionary *matchingDictionary = @{
    kSecClass: kSecClassInternetPassword,
    kSecAttrSecurityDomain: @"example.com" // <-- This may not be quite the
                                           //     right format for the domain.
};
SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) matchingDictionary);
```